# Set table rate shipping to downloadable products

Tags: magento-community, shipping-methods, table-rates, magento-1.5.1

I am running magento 1.5.1.0 I have a physical product associated with downloadable product. So, I want magento table rate shipping to be also applied to downloadable product. There is no such option in the admin panel.

I have imported csv file in the configuration->sales->shipping methods. It works fine for physical products.

I have also seen this option "Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation". But this is not enabling table rate shipping to downloadable products. Can I extend the functionality of this option to include downloadable products too? If yes which file is to be modified?

Is there any other alternative to get this feature? Please give solutions as per my magento version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make bundle product with both physical and downloadable product?

But if you like to activate shipping to work with only downloadable products, it is in:

1. to show Shipping Information (Step 2) ->
   `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping.php` -> `public function isShow()` -> change it to returns true.
2. to show Shipping Method (Step 3) -> `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php` -> `public function isShow()` -> again change it to returns true.